# Selecting specific id from xmlfeed using PHP SimpleXml

Tags: php, simplexml

I have an XML Feed which is using ID's or Types. I need to select the specific node and convert it to a variable.

Example XML Feed:

```
<tour>
<tourName>Amazon Riverboat Adventure</tourName>
<dossierCode>PVIIA</dossierCode>
<tripDetails>
<tripDetail type="StartFinish">ex Lima</tripDetail>
<tripDetail type="What's Included">Lots of stuff </tripDetail>
</tripDetails>
```

I have been extracting this data by using:

```
<?php
if(!$xml=simplexml_load_file('xmlfeed.xml')){
    trigger_error('Error reading XML file',E_USER_ERROR);
}
foreach ($xml->tourName as $tourname)
foreach ($xml->dossierCode as $agentcode)
?>
```

However I am unsure how I can extract the `<tripDetail type="StartFinish">` as $startfinish.

Can anyone help?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php

```
<?php
echo $xmlAsString = <<<XML
<tour>
<tourName>Amazon Riverboat Adventure</tourName>
<dossierCode>PVIIA</dossierCode>
<tripDetails>
<tripDetail type="StartFinish">ex Lima</tripDetail>
<tripDetail type="What's Included">Lots of stuff</tripDetail>
</tripDetails>
</tour>


XML;
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlAsString);
foreach ($xml->tourName as $tourname) {
    var_dump($tourname);
}
foreach ($xml->dossierCode as $agentcode) {
    var_dump($agentcode);
}

foreach ($xml->tripDetails as $tripDetails) {
    foreach ($tripDetails as $tripDetail) {
        $attributes = $tripDetail->attributes();
        echo 'Content of the type: ' . $attributes['type'] . PHP_EOL .
             'Content of the whole tag: ' . $tripDetail  . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. This dumps all the data in my sheet but how can i go about then having the the "ex Lima" to $startfinish and "Lots of Stuff" as $whatsincluded?

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your edit. However this just produces a list. I need to actually be able to assign $startfinish to 'ex lima' etc. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need this? I think you overengineer it then.
Try to work with $attributes['type']. For example if ('StartFinish' == $attributes['type']) { one code } elseif ('WhatIncluded' == $attributes['type']) { another one }

Comment: I like to have order in my scripts so that I can insert particular items into a database as a lot of it isn't required. 
I have used foreach ($xml->tripDetails as $tripDetails) {
    foreach ($tripDetails as $tripDetail) {
        $attributes = $tripDetail->attributes();
        }
        }
if ('StartFinish' == $attributes['type'])
$startfinish = $tripdetail;

however this does still not seem to work. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Matt, may be you need to add {} after if? I just don`t understand what do you want in the result from your code.